# How to open the visual designer on an existing *.w file in Progress Developer studio?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor.

I'm taking my very first steps, using Progress developer Studio (version 4.3): I'm opening a `*.w` file. I was expecting some kind of GUI design form, but even after having chosen the "OpenEdge AppBuilder" or the "OpenEdge Visual Designer perspective, I still only see the `*.w` file in text format.

What can I do in order to open the "Progress Developer Studio graphical GUI designer"? (I hope this feature exists?)

Pressing <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd> does not work, and the context popup looks as follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance and sorry for this very newbie question

Comment: I'd try to move to the most current oe version, move to 11.7 if you're not ready for oe12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm taking my very first steps, using Progress developer Studio

Congratulations!

Hit "shift-F9" or right-click on the editor and choose "View Design"

**Edit**

Apparently, an "ABL GUI Design" needs to be added.

Comment: For your information: I found this URL (https://community.progress.com/s/question/0D54Q000088ckiUSAQ/newbie-question-how-to-open-appbuilder-w-file-in-gui-mode-in-developer-studio), mentioning something about project properties, but I don't even have a project: I've simply opened the `*.w` file without any project reference.

Comment: That would be a problem. You need a project (configuration) in Progress Developer Studio, so that an AVM (ABL Runtime) is started which hosts the AppBuilder design feature. So you'll have to create an OpenEdge project with all it's glory details (PROPATH, Databases, etc.).

Comment: I figured that out, so I've created a first project. In that project, I added a new file "First_Window.w" without anything inside it, but I believe this is not the right way to go. I believe I need to add a window to my project, but I don't know how to do this (or how to configure my project in order to make this possible).